# How can I replace the NULL with a value when using an INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find out why this section of the query wouldn't work

```
ISNULL(nightlyTable.AppointmentID, 
baseTable.AppointmentID) AS AppointmentID
```

Is there another way of writing this section? I need for it to show an AppointmentID when the value is NULL.

Thank you!!

```
USE [AdventureWorksLT]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tempTable] ON

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tempTable]
           ([AppointmentID]
           ,[CustName]
           ,[CustAddress]
           ,[CustPhone])

(SELECT 

    ISNULL(nightlyTable.AppointmentID, 
    baseTable.AppointmentID) AS AppointmentID

    , nightlyTable.CustName
    , nightlyTable.CustAddress
    , nightlyTable.CustPhone 
FROM nightlyTable
FULL OUTER JOIN  baseTable ON (baseTable.AppointmentID = 
nightlyTable.AppointmentID)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT nightlyTable.* EXCEPT SELECT baseTable.*))
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tempTable] OFF;
```

Sample result. I'd like for row 10 to show AppointmentID '10' instead of NULL.

```
AppointmentID   CustName    CustAddress             CustPhone
 1              Salvad0r    1 Main Street North     76197081653
 NULL           NULL        NULL                    NULL
 3              Gilbert     51 Main Street South    23416310745
 NULL           NULL        NULL                    NULL
 5              Jorge       176 Washington Street   7078675309
 NULL           NULL        NULL                    NULL
 7              Stella      192 Church Street       78584836879
 NULL           NULL        NULL                    NULL
 9              Heyy        214 High Street         57288772686
 NULL           NULL        NULL                    NULL
 11             Newbie      21 Jump Street          76086753019
```

Sample tables:

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results would really help.  I really doubt that you intend what this query is doing.

Comment: I'm trying to INSERT data into a blank table. The data is from a result of a comparison query between 'nightlyTable' and the 'baseTable. ' The blank table is 'tempTable'. On 'tempTable', I need to show which row has disappeared completely. From this example, it's row 10. I'd like to insert a value in the AppointmentID column when a row has been deleted when 'nightlyTable' is compared to 'baseTable'.

Comment: I think I have I figured it out. How do I close my noob question? :)

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
ISNULL(nightlyTable.AppointmentID, baseTable.AppointmentID) AS AppointmentID
```

does not work because you have no table alias for `basetable` defined in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to select all the elements in base table that are not in night table.  To do that you left join base table to night table and then look where it was unable to join.  Like this:

```
select b.*
from baseTable b
left join nightlyTable n on n.AppointmentID = b.AppointmentID
where n.AppointmentID is null
```

If you also want to include existing data in nightly table the easy way is with a union, like this:

```
select *
from nightlyTable

UNION ALL

select b.*
from baseTable b
left join nightlyTable n on n.AppointmentID = b.AppointmentID
where n.AppointmentID is null
```

Comment: Plus the changes from the nightly table.